# Add horizontal separator between (landscape) slides

Tags: beamer

Using beamer, I have a created a series of slides. Can I print 2 slides per page (as done in the pdfpages package) but add a horizontal line (not an entire frame) to separate the pages vertically:

I.e., I would like

slide 1

-------     <-- this line is what I want

slide 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it's done (for file beamer.pdf).  How much do you want automated?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document} 
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight,page=1]{beamer}
\vfill\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\vfill
\includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight,page=2]{beamer}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

Answer (score 0):

`pdfpages` has a `picturecommand` option, but I didn't know how to use it in this case. But as it already loads `eso-pic`, it's easy to draw a line on background with it.

Note: I'm not used to `picture`, so if the code can be improved, please do it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\AddToShipoutPicture{
    \thicklines
    \setlength\unitlength{1mm}
    \AtPageCenter{\line(1,0){90}}
    \AtPageCenter{\line(-1,0){90}}
    }

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-, nup=1x2, delta=0 8, scale=.9]{conference-ornate-20min}
\end{document}
```

[image]